# Center align the div to screen works in some browsers and in some dont

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

```css
.txt-loading {
  width: 250px; 
  height: 75px;
  text-align : center;
  position :  fixed;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
  right : 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin : auto;
  font-size : 16px;
  z-index : 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt-loading">Loading...</div>
```

I have seen this code somewhere on internet to center align the div to the screen and it started working on chrome but not working in IE. I am pretty much sure the css styling is wrong to center the div to screen but why does it work in chrome and sometimes also works in IE. May be due to the quirks mode of browser it might work but could anyone tell me why does it work in chrome and why does it not work in IE 11. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your way you stretch the div over the entire window. Use this code for center positioning:

```css
.txt-loading {
  text-align : center;
  position :  fixed;
  top : 50%;
  left : 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  font-size : 16px;
  z-index : 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt-loading">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: great the code you have provided works but also please explain why my css code is not working sometimes or what is wrong or what wrong styling is applied. Thank you